# How do I use ASP.NET Web API Attribute Routing with a complex object parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a Web API action that looks like the following:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/query/hello/{query}")]
public HttpResponseMessage Hello([FromUri]Query query)
{
    return null;
}
```

where the Query class has a public string property named `QueryText`.  When I hit the following URL, I get a 404 error:

```
/api/query/hello?QueryText=bacon
```

This worked before I started using Attribute Routing.  If I have no parameters or primitive type parameters, I can get Attribute Routing to work.  But with a complex parameter, I get 404s.  How does Attribute Routing work with complex action parameters?  Is it compatible with the `FromUri` attribute?

Comment: I am unable to repro your scenario...can you share how your route configuration looks like?...specifically the content in `WebApiConfig.cs`

Comment: @KiranChalla I think I accidentally solved my own problem.  I typoed the sample code.  I edited my question so it reflects the original code I was using. Note the {query} token in the route template.  If I remove this token I believe it works as requested.

Comment: @user2719100 Would you mind clearing up the confusion please - That is, add an answer that explains the issue you had and mark it as "the answer"? TIA :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution here was that the `{query}` token in the Route definition was superfluous.  Removing it, as follows, fixed the issue:

```
[Route("api/query/hello")]
```

Comment: Man, I so wish I could do a +5! Been struggling with this for 30 mins on a Friday Evening! Thanks!

Comment: How does this change for http post with url encoded parameters?

Answer (score 1):

The [FromUri] attribute will be needed because you're reading from the URL. Your route should look something like:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Hello([FromUri]Query query)
{
    //Implement whatever
    return null;
}
```

/api/{Controller Name}/hello?QueryText=bacon

Should then work correctly.

The model binder will take whatever query parameters you provided then try to bind whatever is inside that `Query` object. I'd worry about the Route Attribute after you've got it working first.

Comment: I simplified the example to better communicate the problem.  The actual parameter class contains much more than a single string property :)